# How to get an object class into SQL Query c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, class

I would like to put the values of object 'gebruiker' from class 'Gebruikersklasse' to the query in the buttonclick. The query will be sent to the 'Databaseconnection' class and will be executed there. I'm getting an error if I run this. It tells me that gebruikers.Naam can't be found. So he can't find an object called 'gebruiker' I think?

If I change the query to manually values, it works.

I am using these classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BurnThatFat
{
    class Gebruikerklasse
    {
        public string Naam;
        public string Achternaam;
        public int Leeftijd;
        public string Geslacht;
        public int Huidiggewicht;
        public int Streefgewicht;
        public string Gebruikersnaam;
        public string Email;
        public string Wachtwoord;
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// voor sql connectie.
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

and this is the code for the databaseconnection (executing the queries)

```
namespace BurnThatFat
{
  class databaseconnection
  {
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\V11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Cihan\Documents\BurnThatFat\BurnThatFat\Database2.mdf;Integrated Security=True";



    public void QueryToDatabase(string commandText, Gebruikerklasse gebruiker)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
     }
  }
}
```

and this is the `buttonclick` code:

```
private void btn_emailvolgende_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gebruiker = new Gebruikerklasse();
    gebruiker.Naam = Convert.ToString(tb_voornaam.Text);
    gebruiker.Achternaam = Convert.ToString(tb_achternaam.Text);
    gebruiker.Leeftijd = Convert.ToInt32(nud_leeftijd.Value);
    gebruiker.Geslacht = Convert.ToString(cb_geslacht.Text);
    gebruiker.Huidiggewicht = Convert.ToInt32(nud_huidiggewicht.Value);
    gebruiker.Streefgewicht = Convert.ToInt32(nud_streefgewicht.Value);
    gebruiker.Gebruikersnaam = Convert.ToString(tb_gebruikersnaam2.Text);
    gebruiker.Email = Convert.ToString(tb_email.Text);
    gebruiker.Wachtwoord = Convert.ToString(tb_wachtwoordsignup.Text);

    db.QueryToDatabase("INSERT INTO Gebruiker ([Gebruiker-ID], Naam, Achternaam, Leeftijd, Geslacht, Huidig_gewicht, Streef_gewicht, Gebruikersnaam, Email, Wachtwoord) VALUES(1, gebruiker.Naam, gebruiker.Achternaam, gebruiker.Leeftijd, gebruiker.Geslacht, gebruiker.Huidiggewicht, gebruiker.Streefgewicht, gebruiker.Gebruikersnaam, gebruiker.Email, gebruiker.Wachtwoord);", gebruiker);
    gb_email.Visible = false;
}
```

Edit:

The exact error that I'm getting:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in BurnThatFat.exe
>
> Additional information: The multi-part identifier "gebruiker.Naam" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "gebruiker.Achternaam" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "gebruiker.Leeftijd" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "gebruiker.Geslacht" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "gebruiker.Huidiggewicht" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "gebruiker.Streefgewicht" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "gebruiker.Gebruikersnaam" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "gebruiker.Email" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "gebruiker.Wachtwoord" could not be bound.

Comment: What is the entire and exact error? While the two answers are correct in that you pass your object to `QuerryToDatabase` but you never even use it, I think your problem occurs before you get there.

Comment: @crowcoder i added the exact error to the original post.

Comment: ok, so it is a SQL error. Do as one of the answers show you becasue you cannot put `gebruiker.Naam` in the string because it does not expand the actual value of the variable that way.

Comment: Can you take a look at my question @2ndanswer ?

Comment: While `AddWithValue` is not the preferred way to set parameter values, and you don't need to explicitly close a connection in a `using` block, @Paweł Łukasik 's answer looks ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `gebruiker` values to the SQL command. Right now you're not doing that. Your `QueryToDatabase` should be extended with argument passing

```
public void QueryToDatabase(string commandText, Gebruikerklasse gebruiker)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam", gebruiker.Naam);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Achternaam, gebruiker.Achternaam);
        // do the same with others properties in gebruiker

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Also your query is wrong. You need to tell SQL where it should look for parameters.

```
"INSERT INTO Gebruiker ([Gebruiker-ID], Naam, Achternaam, Leeftijd, Geslacht, Huidig_gewicht, Streef_gewicht, Gebruikersnaam, Email, Wachtwoord) VALUES(1, @Naam, @Achternaam, @Leeftijd, @Geslacht, @Huidiggewicht, @Streefgewicht, @Gebruikersnaam, @Email, @Wachtwoord);
```

The names in the SQL query and names used in `AddWithValue` should match.

If you do not want to do that manually - have a look at ORMs.

Comment: What happens if I send a query without the parameter @naam?
will it crash or just ignore it and go ahead with @achternaam?

Comment: I tried this and get the following error:
{"Incorrect syntax near ';'."}

Comment: That error is solved, now this one:

{"String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: @Gigitex that means that one of your columns is too short for the data that's being put in it

Comment: So I should change this to Varcar(MAX)?

Comment: not necessary MAX, but it will work.  MAX is the limit you can give but sometimes it doesn't make sense to have such long columns if you know that it will not get over i.e. 2000 chars

Comment: The parameters do work, but if I only want to use @|Gebruikersnaam & @Wachtwoord to login with another button it tells me that the other parameters have no value. How do I fix this?

Comment: for login you need different query - this one stores the data into the DB

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because SQL is not finding any table or reference with that name, you can achieve something similar with a stored procedure.

First create the procedure in sql:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertGebruiker(
    @Naam VARCHAR(50),
    @Achternaam VARCHAR(50),
    @Leeftijd INT, 
    @Geslacht VARCHAR(50),
    @Huidiggewicht INT,
    @Streefgewicht INT,
    @Gebruikersnaam VARCHAR(50),
    @Email VARCHAR(50),
    @Wachtwoord VARCHAR(50),
)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Gebruiker(
    [Gebruiker-ID],
    Naam,
    Achternaam,
    Leeftijd, 
    Geslacht,
    Huidig_gewicht,
    Streef_gewicht,
    Gebruikersnaam,
    Email,
    Wachtwoord) 
    VALUES (
    1,
    @Naam,
    @Achternaam,
    @Leeftijd , 
    @Geslacht,
    @Huidiggewicht ,
    @Streefgewicht ,
    @Gebruikersnaam ,
    @Email,
    @Wachtwoord,
)
END
```

Now from your c# code:

```
public void QueryToDatabase(string procedureName, Gebruikerklasse gebruiker)
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam", gebruiker.Naam);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Achternaam", gebruiker.Achternaam);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Leeftijd", gebruiker.Leeftijd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Geslacht", gebruiker.Geslacht);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Huidiggewicht", gebruiker.Huidiggewicht);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Streefgewicht", gebruiker.Streefgewicht);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gebruikersnaam", gebruiker.Gebruikersnaam);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", gebruiker.Email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wachtwoord", gebruiker.Wachtwoord);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

        }
    }
```

And you just call it using the name of your procedure:

```
db.QueryToDatabase("insertGebruiker", gebruiker);
```