# SQL C# not all parameters used

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters

Someone suggested me to use parameters for my sign up form.

link to it: [How to get an object class into SQL Query c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505362/how-to-get-an-object-class-into-sql-query-c/41505898?noredirect=1#comment70226641_41505898)

I want to use the same class to login, but I get the following error:

my database class uses all the parameters to sign up. But if I want to use the same class to login, I only need 2 of them. Called: Gebruikersnaam(username) and Wachtwoord (password).

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: The parameterized query '(@Naam nvarchar(4000),@Achternaam nvarchar(1),@Leeftijd int,@Ges' expects the parameter '@Naam', which was not supplied.

This is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// voor sql connectie.
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace BurnThatFat
{
    class databaseconnection
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\V11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Cihan\Documents\BurnThatFat\BurnThatFat\Database2.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        bool succes = true;

        public bool Succes
        {
            get { return succes; }
            set { succes = value; }
        }

        public void QueryToDatabase(string commandText, Gebruikerklasse gebruiker)
        {
            // nieuwe connectie maken
            // ontvangt de query vanuit 'buttonclick' en voert hem hier uit
            // als ExecuteNonQuery niet kan worden uitgevoerd is er iets fout gegaan. D.m.v een bool moet hij dan een bericht tonen
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam", gebruiker.Naam);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Achternaam", gebruiker.Achternaam);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Leeftijd", gebruiker.Leeftijd);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Geslacht", gebruiker.Geslacht);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Huidiggewicht", gebruiker.Huidiggewicht);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Streefgewicht", gebruiker.Streefgewicht);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gebruikersnaam", gebruiker.Gebruikersnaam);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", gebruiker.Email);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wachtwoord", gebruiker.Wachtwoord);

                int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (a > 0)
                {
                    Succes = true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    Succes = false;
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the Gebruiker class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BurnThatFat
{
    class Gebruikerklasse
    {
        public string Naam;
        public string Achternaam;
        public int Leeftijd;
        public string Geslacht;
        public int Huidiggewicht;
        public int Streefgewicht;
        public string Gebruikersnaam;
        public string Email;
        public string Wachtwoord;

    }
}
```

and this is the buttonclick code to sign up (this works)

```
 private void btn_emailvolgende_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gebruiker = new Gebruikerklasse();
            gebruiker.Naam = Convert.ToString(tb_voornaam.Text);
            gebruiker.Achternaam = Convert.ToString(tb_achternaam.Text);
            gebruiker.Leeftijd = Convert.ToInt32(nud_leeftijd.Value);
            gebruiker.Geslacht = Convert.ToString(cb_geslacht.Text);
            gebruiker.Huidiggewicht = Convert.ToInt32(nud_huidiggewicht.Value);
            gebruiker.Streefgewicht = Convert.ToInt32(nud_streefgewicht.Value);
            gebruiker.Gebruikersnaam = Convert.ToString(tb_gebruikersnaam2.Text); 
            gebruiker.Email = Convert.ToString(tb_email.Text);
            gebruiker.Wachtwoord = Convert.ToString(tb_wachtwoordsignup.Text);

            db.QueryToDatabase("INSERT INTO Gebruiker([Gebruiker-ID], Naam, Achternaam, Leeftijd, Geslacht, Huidig_gewicht, Streef_gewicht, Gebruikersnaam, Email, Wachtwoord) VALUES(13, @Naam, @Achternaam, @Leeftijd, @Geslacht, @Huidiggewicht, @Streefgewicht, @Gebruikersnaam, @Email, @Wachtwoord);", gebruiker);

            // Als dit is gedaan, kijken of het is gelukt of niet. Als het geen succes is, geef foutmelding weer. Als het wel een succes is, spring naar Log in scherm
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            if (db.Succes == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Er is iets fout gegaan, sluit de applicatie af en probeer het overnieuw");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Account met succes aangemaakt, log nu in");
                gb_email.Visible = false;

                gb_login.Visible = true;
            }
        }
}
```

And this is the buttonclick code to log in (doesn't work, gives me the error shown above)

```
private void btn_loginvolgende_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gebruiker = new Gebruikerklasse();
            gebruiker.Gebruikersnaam = Convert.ToString(tb_gebruikersnaamlogin.Text);
            gebruiker.Wachtwoord = Convert.ToString(tb_wachtwoordlogin.Text);
            gebruiker.Achternaam = "a";
            gebruiker.Email = "a";
            gebruiker.Geslacht = "a";
            gebruiker.Huidiggewicht = 1;
            gebruiker.Streefgewicht = 1;
            gebruiker.Leeftijd = 1;

            db.QueryToDatabase("Select count (*) from Gebruiker where Wachtwoord = @Wachtwoord AND Gebruikersnaam = @Gebruikersnaam;", gebruiker);
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            if (db.Succes == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login gegevens kloppen niet!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("U bent met succes ingelogd");
            }

            // hier moet nog een GB!!!!!!
        }
```

Comment: Cihan, Check *AddWithValue* needs `@varname` or `varname`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code, you are adding the parameter @Naam to both commands.  In the query that works, you assign a value to gebruiker.Naam and assign that value to the parameter.  In the one that doesn't work, gebruiker.Naam is null, and you try to assign null to the parameter.

Which leads to the tricky part (until you get used to it) - SQL Server uses DBNull, and C# uses null, and they aren't the same thing (even though you may expect them to be.)  If you want a SQL parameter to be "null", then you want to say:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyParameter", DBNull.Value);
```

The easiest solution to this would be to add separate methods in your db class for login and signup.  That way, you are only creating the parameters that you actually need, and you don't need to add a million checks for null values in your gebruiker class.

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for your parameter Naam. You missed it when assigning values in your login.

gebruiker.Naam = ???

Answer (score 0):

You should be include all parameters value. In code you missed the parameter value at btn_loginvolgende_Click method.

```
private void btn_loginvolgende_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    gebruiker.Naam = Convert.ToString("test");
    ..

    }
```